# jQuery performance - class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="target">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which selector is more efficient?

- `$('.foo > .bar > .target')`
- `$('.foo .bar .target')`
- `$('.target')`

Did I order them correctly? :)

Comment: All of them are different. What's the point in comparing them?

Comment: @tamir Don't get bothered by micro-performance issues like this. Write selectors that are specific enough for your needs, and don't worry too much about this type of stuff.

Comment: @Alexander Not really.. at least not for the HTML he has posted. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be careful not to get too caught up in these types of issues - micro-optimization can really ruin a project. Not that it isn't good to ponder from time to time, but sincerely, be cautious.

If you still would like to know which of those three are faster, you can setup a quick performance test via http://jsperf.com and give them all three a run against that markup.  Fortunately for you, I've saved you the hassle and setup the test myself ;) http://jsperf.com/css-selector-specificity

Results:

```
                              Ops/Sec
----------------------------+---------+--------+------------
$('.foo > .bar > .target'); |  78,379 | ±6.54% | 65% slower
$('.foo .bar .target');     |  78,499 | ±7.72% | 66% slower
$('.target');               | 213,488 | ±0.39% | fastest
```

As you can see, the simplest of the three was much faster. Your results will vary from browser to browser. For instance, the above is from Chrome version 23. When I ran this test in Internet Explorer 10, it was even faster, with over 216,000 operations a second.

Answer (score 1):

$("#foo") is most efficient
but 
$('.foo').find(".target")
i have read is the best  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/

Comment: I realize that but i was only stating that finding element by id was faster than finding by class name ;-)